# dynamically changing class in rails haml file

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, haml

I have the following line of code in a haml file

```
%a#mypage{:href => hub_path(@user), :class => "#{path.match('(hub)') ? 'current': ''}"}
```

What this does is ensure the correct item on a navigation bar is highlighted. However, I need the same item to be highlighted if any one of several paths are matched.

So, above we have the path matched to hub. I need it to return true if the path is matched to hub, or item2, or item3.

No idea where to begin. I've tried putting in "||" into the class to see if I could just list them but this didn't work. Is there a way to do "includes" when specifying the match?

continued...

So I took the advice of the posters below but still couldnt' make it work

I'm at this point to test it

```
- path = request.fullpath
- if path.match(/\(performance_hub|objectives|deliverables\)/)
  true
- else 
  fail
  %br
= path
```

Even though the path is

```
/users/170/hub
```

it is still returning false. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Try a regexp: `path.match(/(hub)|(item2)|(item3)/) ? 'current': ''` (http://rubular.com/r/kaoufeF1GL)

Comment: Why would you expect `/users/170/hub` to match `/\(performance_hub|objectives|deliverables\)/`?

Answer (score 1):

Try with regex instead of string

```
:class => "#{path.match(/\(hub|item2|item3\)/) ? 'current': ''
```

This will search for `(hub)` or `(item2)` or `(item3)`

Comment: Actually this will search for `(hub` or `item2` or `item3)`. It’s not clear what the question is actually asking for (especially after the edit) but it looks like it should be either something like `/\((hub|item2|item3)\)/` (i.e. with literal parens) or `/hub|item2|item3/`.

Answer (score 0):

The answer ended up being this

```
%a#mylink{:href => hub_path(@user), :class => "#{%w(hub objective deliverable).any?{|w| path.match(w)} ? 'current': ''}"}
```